# Let $P=\{p_1,p_2,\ldots ,p_n\}$ the set of the first $n$ prime numbers, thus

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $P=\{p_1,p_2,\ldots ,p_n\}$ the set of the first $n$ prime numbers and let $S\subseteq P$. Let 
$$A=\prod_{p\in S}p$$ and $$B=\prod_{p\in P-S}p.$$ Show that if 
$A+B<p_{n+1}^2$, then the number $A+B$ is prime. 
Also, if 
$$1<|A-B|<p_{n+1}^2,$$ then the number $|A-B|$ is prime.

Comment: What is $S$ defined as?

Comment: @hungryformath A smaller set of P, that also contains prime numbers

Comment: HINT: If $n<(p_{n+1})^2$ where $p_{n+1}$ is a prime than we just need to check if it is divisble by $p_i$ where $1 \le i \le n.

Comment: @graydad. If $P=\{2,3\}$ and $S=\{2\}$ then $A=\prod_{p\in S}=2$ and  $B=3.$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

For any geeral $n$, $n<(p_{k+1})^2$ where $p_{k+1}$ is the $k+1$th prime than we just need to check if $n$ is divisble by $p_i$ where $1 \le i \le n$.

But note that for any $p_i$ $$p_i \in S, P-S$$ is a contradiction. Thus, since $p_i$ is a prime it can only divide one of $A$ or $B$. In other words, if $A \equiv 0 \pmod {p_i}$ then $B \not \equiv 0 \pmod {p_i}$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe due to Bertrand's postulate there is a finite (and relatively small) number of pairs $(n, S)$ for which $A + B < p_{n+1}^2$. An interesting satellite problem is to identify all such pairs; then the proposed problem is solved by inspection.

Comment: Indeed, by the AM/GM inequality $A+B \ge 2\sqrt{AB} = 2\exp(\theta(p_n)/2)$ where $\theta(x) = \sum_{p\le x} \log x$, and Rosser-Schoenfeld give a lower bound on $\theta(x)$ for $x\ge41$. One can go on to then show that the largest possible $n$ for which there exists $A+B<p_{n+1}^2$ is $n=5$.